# how to pass context value to specific input over the form.as_table in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i need to pass value from my view to specific label in the my form.as_table
in this case look at live output template i want assign t_v_a as context   to t_v_a as quittanceForm.as_table

view.py

```
def Tva_Calculate(request):
form_data=forms.QuittanceRegister(request.POST or None)
t_v_a=0
if form_data.is_valid():
    t_v_a=form_data.cleaned_data['loyer_acteul_411000']*9/100

context ={

    'quittanceForm': form_data,
    't_v_a':t_v_a

}
return render(request,'quittance.html',context)
```

template.py

```
 <center>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <h1>Register new Quittance</h1>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table border="1">

           {{quittanceForm.as_table}} 
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Register now</button>
    <button type="submit">Calculate_tva</button>
</form>
{{t_v_a}}
</center>
```

live output template
     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6FJL.png)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to render your form manually. It gives you more freedom.

See: [Rendering Fields Manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)

Answer (score 0):

```
class formModel(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = yourModel
    fields = ['fields here']
    widgets = {
        'tva_attribute':forms.TextInput(attrs={'value': YOUR_TVA_VALUE}),
        }
```

**Try this hopefully it will work**